# Удалить элемент из ArrayList kotlin

Tags: kotlin, arraylist

Пытаюсь удалить элемент из списка. Но индекс брать тот который у меня задается так:

```
answerIds.indexOf(finishedTasksGroups[i])
```

общая конструкция такая:

```
for (i in 1 until finishedTasksGroups.size) {
answersTxts.removeAt(answerIds.indexOf(finishedTasksGroups[i]))
}
```

но по итогу удаляется не так как нужно. В `finishedTasksGroups` у меня 3 элемента, в `answersTxts` 5. `finishedTasksGroups`  выглядит так: `[1,2,3]` а у `answersTxts` должно по итогу быть показано 4 и 5 элементы, а показывается 1,3 и 5. Не могу понять что делаю не так, вроде бы все верно записано, но раз считает не так как нужно значит где-то ошибка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это из-за того, что список, надо которым идет работа, в процессе этой самой работы изменяется и после каждой итерации список уже совсем другой.

Пройдемся:

i = 1:

`finishedTasksGroups[1]` = 2.

`answerIds.indexOf(2)` = 1.

`answersTxts.removeAt(1)` удаляет элемент 2. Т.е. нулевой элемент (1) остается. Результат: `[1, 3, 4, 5]`

i = 2:

`finishedTasksGroups[2]` = 3.

`answerIds.indexOf(3)` = 2.

`answersTxts.removeAt(2)` удаляет 4, потому что после предыдущего удаления элемент 4 сдвинулся на место 2. Итог: `[1, 3, 5]`

Цикл завершен.

Решение: идти с другого конца.

```
for (i in finishedTasksGroups.size-1 downTo 0)
```

Comment: возможно вопрос глупый, но тем не менее спрошу - почему там -1 стоит?

Comment: Потому что размер массива считается с 1, а элементы нумеруются с 0. Поэтому последний элемент имеет номер array.size-1, а элемента по адресу [array.size] не существует.

Comment: а то что до 0 это тоже так нужно? просто в этом массиве не может быть элементов равных 0, то есть могут быть только 1,2,3 и 4, может правильнее написать до 1, или нет?

Comment: Так это не значение, а порядковый номер.